# iterate through all struct member

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to iterate through all of `PATTERNS`'s members. I cannot use `vector`. Ideally, I want to be able to get the next member of the `struct` and reset it when the end is reached. What I understand is that I essentially want a linked list. Thing is that I have many `struct` such as this one and I find it inefficient for me to create a `struct` containing one array with a pointer to the next `struct` containing the next array.

Q: How would you iterate through all of the `struct`'s members?

```
struct PATTERNS {
  bool P0[3] = {0, 0, 1};
  bool P1[3] = {0, 1, 1};
  bool P2[3] = {1, 1, 1};
};
```

Edit: to answer @user17732522 - I'm trying to replicate code from python (itertools). It's mainly for convenience of use and somewhat more OOP. The quick fix is just to make a 2D bool array.

Comment: Short version is you can't, C++ doesn't have any built-in introspection functionality that would allow you to automatically find out what members a given type has

Comment: Could you show a use case for this?

Comment: With that structure you'd have to add a very special iterator type that you return from `PATTERNS::begin()` It's probably better to make it `bool P[9] =  {...};` and add `bool& operator()(size_t y, size_t x) { return P[y*3 + x]; }` to the class to access the 1d array as a 2d array ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gerh65xx3))

Comment: If all members are of the same type, why not use `bool P[3][3]`? (or `std::array<std::array<bool, 3>, 3>`)

Comment: A bidimensional array would be clean.

Comment: If you just want to be able to iterate over the elements like an iterator, that is possible by defining a custom iterator for it that just does the appropriate member/element selection. You can also apply some template trickery to deduce the number of elements since the type is aggregate.

Comment: *I'm trying to replicate code from python (itertools)* -- And right there is the crux of the problem.  The issue is attempting to try and write C++ using Python (or any other computer language) as a model.  Do not do this -- if you do this, you will have a combination of things wrong:  1) The code will be buggy.  2) The code will be inefficient, both in what's written and in the execution time, and 3) The code will look weird to an actual C++ programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "You can't.".

C++ doesn't offer any reflection features because they limit of the language, when maintaining backwards compatibility.

You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and a little type erasure (like [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)) to achieve what you want.

If you *really* want reflection you can use [Boost Reflect Library](https://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/) or look into what extensions your compiler supports.  I wouldn't recommend either of those options though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to iterate members in C++ (without meta programming).

You could make a small change to use an array as a member. You can iterate arrays in C++:

```
struct PATTERNS {
    bool P[3][3] = {
        {0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
    };
};
```

Referring to the subarrays with names is still possible, but it requires considerable boilerplate:

```
union PATTERNS {
    using PA = bool[3];
    struct {
        PA P[3];
        operator       PA&() &        { return  P[0]; }
        operator const PA&() const &  { return  P[0]; }
        PA* operator&()               { return &P[0]; }
    } P0;
    
    struct {
        PA P[3];
        operator       PA&() &        { return  P[1]; }
        operator const PA&() const &  { return  P[1]; }
        PA* operator&()               { return &P[1]; }
    } P1;

    struct {
        PA P[3];
        operator       PA&() &        { return  P[2]; }
        operator const PA&() const &  { return  P[2]; }
        PA* operator&()               { return &P[2]; }
    } P2;

    struct {
        PA P[3];
        PA* begin() { return std::begin(P); }
        PA* end()   { return std::end(P);   }
    } P;
};
```

I couldn't figure out if this can work with default member initialiser such as the one in your example.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "static reflection". C++ doesn't support it yet.

In the meantime you can use a code generator to look at your code and produce functions to iterate through elements of the struct.

That can be done using Google's Protocol Buffers (protobuf), although you'll have to write your structs in protobuf and then use the generated C++ code.

I've seen people use a different code generator: PyBind11 which interfaces between C++11 and Python. It produces object declarations for C++ and Python to use, and then without changing any of the C++ code, you can use dynamic reflection in Python to gain the feature you were looking for in C++. PyBind11 can be useful for setting-up test environments.

I think PyBind11 scans your C++ code. The process is not entirely automatic, but what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make an array of arrays (often called a 2d array). You can then add an iterator to your class to simplify iterating over all the elements.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct PATTERNS {
    bool P[3][3] = {
        {0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
    };

    // references to sub-arrays if you need them:
    bool (&P0)[3] = P[0];
    bool (&P1)[3] = P[1];
    bool (&P2)[3] = P[2];

    // basic iterator support (not at all a complete iterator implementation)
    struct iterator {

        // non-const dereferencing
        bool& operator*() { return p[i / 3][i % 3]; };

        iterator& operator++() {
            ++i;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const { return i == rhs.i; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); } 

        size_t i;          // current index
        bool (&p)[3][3];   // a reference to the actual bool[3][3]
    };

    // iterate over all the 3x3 bools:
    iterator begin() { return {0, P}; }
    iterator end() { return {9, P}; }

    // iterate over a specific row of bools:
    iterator begin(size_t row) { return {row * 3, P}; }
    iterator end(size_t row) { return {(row + 1) * 3, P}; }
};
```

Example use:

```cpp
int main() {
    PATTERNS pat;
    // all
    for (bool v : pat) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // a certain row
    size_t row = 1;
    for (auto it = pat.begin(row); it != pat.end(row); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well a quick and dirty way is to simply cast your structure to an array of `bool` and print that:

```
PATTERNS ptn;
auto p = (bool *)&ptn;

copy(p, p + 9, ostream_iterator<bool>(cout, " "));
```

You can see it in action [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/L7uqVOVKKbn).

Just take care that there's no compiler alignment being performed or you'll run into trouble. Use `#pragma pack` or your specific compiler's flavor to disable it.

Comment: You can even get rid of the magic number `9` if you want, with a simple `sizeof(ptn) / sizeof(bool)` (which is most likely the same as `sizeof(ptn)`, but not necessarily).

Comment: While this is likely to work, it is also clearly undefined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: I don't believe he asked for a standards-conforming answer, though if you can quote where he did I will stand corrected. Couple that with the fact that this will work in every major compiler and OS and I'm fine with it overall. You're free to downvote as you wish though.

Comment: I did not intend the downvotes. I would expect it to work in practice under the conditions you have given, but I think it is important to indicate when methods that technically have undefined behavior are used. (E.g. in the future compilers might use more sophisticated optimizations around these.) That's all my comment was meant to do.

Comment: Don't take Undefined Behavior lightly. Write clean code that also works 10 years from now. Especially in situations, where there are lots of good solutions.